# Create sequential variable names using a loop in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, variables, structure

I'm trying to create variable names using a loop.

Specifically, I am using this structure:

```
struct card{
    string rank;
    string suit;
};
```

This is the rest of my code as it stands, and where it says "card+i" is where I need it to say "card1", or "card2", etc.

```
string aSuit[4] = {" Hearts"," Clubs"," Diamonds"," Spades"};
string aRank[13] = {"A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};
string aDeck[52];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int s=0; s<4; s++) {
        for (int r=0; r<13; r++) {
            card card+i;
            card+i.rank = aRank[r];
            card+i.suit = aSuit[s];
            cout << card + i.rank << card + i.suit << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This isn't possible, variable names all disappear at compile time. Maybe use a `std::map`? (Ok strictly that's not entirely true, what with debug symbols, dynamic linking, etc).

Comment: But isn't this exactly why there are arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use arrays instead:

```
card cards[52];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int s = 0; s<4; s++) {
        for (int r = 0; r<13; r++) {
            cards[i].rank = aRank[r];
            cards[i].suit = aSuit[s];
            cout << cards[i].rank << cards[i].suit << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You *think* this is the best solution, but I can assure you, it is not.  Tying your logic to the names of variables is a bad, bad idea, from a logical as well as maintenance standpoibnt.  What you really want is a collection which can associate one piece of data (in this case, a string) with another.

Look into a data structure like a [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use arrays for this, they allow a single variable to contain a group of items.

Then you simply use the variable name with an index, such as:

```
int xyzzy[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    xyzzy[i] = i * 7;
// gives 0, 7, 14, 21, 28
```

In fact, your code already *has* arrays representing the suits and card face values, not really that different from what you need here, so I'm not certain why you didn't make the logic-leap to using them for the cards as well. But that's basically how you'd do it.

Comment: The issue I'm having using an array, is to preserve the .suit and .rank of each card in the array. Would I need to create an array[104] {card1.rank, card1.suit, card2.rank, card2.suit, etc...} ?

Comment: @user1846123 You've got an array of the wrong things. You don't want an array of `string`. See my answer.

Comment: @user1846123, the answer to that is to define an array of that _structure_ of yours, and use things like `card[7].rank`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible. When you compile a C++ program, any concept of variable names completely disappears. It can't generate variable names at run time because they just don't exist.

However, there is a way to do this, of course. This is precisely what arrays are for. They give you a whole set of objects that you can index by number (`i`, in your case). You already have a variable named `aDeck` but I think you've defined it incorrectly. Did you perhaps want:

```
card aDeck[52];
```

Now you'll have a deck of 52 cards. Each card in this deck has `suit` and `rank` members. You can access each member of the array with `aDeck[i]`. So change the inside of your loop to:

```
aDeck[i].rank = aRank[r];
aDeck[i].suit = aSuit[s];
```